# Does InstallShield Limited Edition Support 64 bit Installer?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, installshield-le

I just started to learn InstallShield LE because it seems the only "officially" supported installer project. But I have one simple question that I can't even get a absolute answer: does ISLE support building a 64bit installer? I am asking because I found at least two posts saying that it is impossible, like this one:
[Replacing VS Setup projects with Installshield Limited Edition problematic](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/643878/replacing-vs-setup-projects-with-installshield-limited-edition-problematic). However, I can't get a (negative or positive)confirmation from flexera's website. They don't even seem to have a forum for LE version. Anyone has the experience can confirm that? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

InstallShield Limited Edition does not support creating 64-bit installations at this time. This is covered in the installed documentation in a topic about upgrading to other versions of InstallShield. It's also implied in the online document "Does InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2010 Meet All Your Installation Requirements?" where it mentions "Support for 64-Bit COM Extraction" is not included in the limited edition (this is just one of many aspects of 64-bit installations).

Comment: Today's release of InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2013 changes this: the answer is now yes.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to produce 64bit setup using InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2013?